# How do I get value from span and assign it to a php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, trygetvalue

How can I take the value of:

```
<span name="MinPrice" class="irs-from">0</span>
<span name="MaxPrice" class="irs-to">0</span>
```

And assign them to PHP variables:

```
$MinPrice
$MaxPrice
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
   var base_html =
    '<span class="irs">' +
    '<span class="irs-line" tabindex="-1"><span class="irs-line-left"></span><span class="irs-line-mid"></span><span class="irs-line-right"></span></span>' +
    '<span class="irs-min">0</span><span class="irs-max">1</span>' +
    '<span name="MinPrice" class="irs-from">0</span><span name="MaxPrice" class="irs-to">0</span><span class="irs-single">0</span>' +
    '</span>' +
    '<span class="irs-grid"></span>' +
    '<span class="irs-bar"></span>';
```

I use form:

```
<form action="<?php echo languageURL(0, ''.$g['url'].'products.html'); ?>" method="get">

<div class="wrapper" style=" padding:20px;">
  <div class="range-slider">
      <input type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" />
  </div>
</div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn-primary goo" value="Търсене" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to put values of client-side elements in to PHP you will need to send a request to the server, either via a `form` or through AJAX. Also note that `span` elements don't have values, they have innerText/Html

Comment: You need to send the values via ajax

Comment: And not many of us are going to WADE THRU 100's of lines of code looking for SOMETHING... who knows what.

Comment: **NB** Php will not execute on your products page. the page is a .html ext it must be a .php file

Comment: I fixed the post. Sorry !

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  See here on the form `<form action="<?php echo languageURL(0, ''.$g['url'].'products.html');`

Comment: No, there is no such page as "products.html". Processing through the language code and going to .html is otherwise .php

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks, I missed that edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AJAX to assign your values to PHP variables.
You can send the form data like this in jQuery:

```
function sendData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {$("#formID").serialize(), MinPrice: $('#minSpan span').html(), MaxPrice: $('#maxSpan span').html()},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html)
        {
            // do something ...
        }
    });
}
```

In this case the data is sent via POST and your form needs an ID (e.g. id="formID").

Update:
Now also the values of the spans are sent, here with the IDs id="minSpan" and id="maxSpan".
In ajax.php you can read the POST values, try it with to see all available values:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Ok, but how to send the information exactly to the php form:

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Hello ! Thank you ! 
When I try to enter it into the body of the code, the code crashes.

Comment: I try this: $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../include/aside.php",
        data: {$("#filter").serialize(), MinPrice: $("#minSpan span").html(), MaxPrice: $("#maxSpan span").html()},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html)
        {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
    
});

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments

1. Span doesn't have values they have innerHTML.
2. You will need to do it through ajax(if you want to do it using jQuery).

Now To get the value out of **base_html** variable, you will first need to parse HTML string and then take out values from it i.e.

```
var min = $.parseHTML( base_html).find(".irs-from").text();
var max = $.parseHTML( base_html).find(".irs-to").text();
$.ajax({url: "value_set.php?min="+min+"max="+max, success: function(result){
   //do whatever you like to do here
  }});
```